# Content Type showing up in edit form?

Tags: content-type, edit-form

I have a library with a couple of custom content types all inheriting from Document Set and in the edit form the Content Type field shows up. I would rather remove it because it doesn't make any sense for these items to change content type after they are created. I added`<FieldRef ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" ShowInEditForm="FALSE"/>` to the content type and list definition, but it's still showing up. How do I remove the content type field from the edit form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `ContentType` field property `ShowInEditForm="FALSE"` will not affect the visibility of *Content Type Choice* control in the Edit form.

The visibility of Content Type Choice control ([ChangeContentType class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.changecontenttype.aspx)) is determined by the following conditions:

- whether content types are enabled for the list ([SPList.ContentTypesEnabled property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.changecontenttype.aspx))
- the number of available content types for a list are *more than 1*

### How to hide Content Type Choice control

One option would be to hide the control on the client-side:

```
$(function() {
  $("select[id*='ContentTypeChoice']").closest('tr').hide(); 
});
```

> Compatible with SharePoint 2010/2013

Answer (score -1):

Go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Allow management of content types?

Set this to No.

Comment: This would remove content types from the library completely. The requirement is to disable the change of a content type in edit mode.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis I don't think it will remove the content types. It will just hide the ability to manage them and at the same time hide the option to change them from the Edit form. At least that is how it is working for me.

Comment: It must be possible somehow because a Workflow Task does **not** show under the *New* option and neither on the Edit Form. But is listed as ContentType  ![](http://i.imgur.com/iRWMI7U.jpg)

Comment: This worked for me in SharePoint 2019